# drupal 7 views horizontal align not working in grid?

Tags: 7, views

First time ever had this problem with views not rendering images to horizontal align in grid.

I have the Views module version 7.x-3.5 installed on Drupal 7.18.

I actually realized it is aligning for immediate view of links, but not within the view after clicking a link. How do I make all images horizontal align?

Comment: clear you cache

Comment: have done still not working

Answer (score 2):

You can horizontally align things with CSS

e.g

```
.container{
  text-align:center;
}
```

You can also align using a margin or padding.

In your case:

```
.view-galleryofimages .views-view-grid {
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Should suffice.

See this summary for more info: [CSS Horizontal Align](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)

Comment: Thanks but where do I place that css code for views?

Comment: The CSS will depend on your HTML markup. You can add it to any of your theme css files, e.g: style.css in your theme dir

Comment: Trouble is all of this is in the linked view created by a module so I cannot locate the specific html.

Comment: I mean I can easily edit my themes css but cannot find where to create a div or class for content added in module.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the HTML comes from, presumably you can see it in your browser? If so, use firebug or webkit right-click > "Inspect Element" to study the HTML markup.

Comment: well I can view source which I just did but it is already set as hidden in immediate view as rendered by module, I think I need to use eva field or something working within views module to do it.

Comment: can u tell me would it be .views-container-field-item even {
text align:center;
}
where the image dir in source is <div class="field-item even">?

Comment: Heh, when you haven't posted a URL or an HTML example, how can I tell if that would be correct?

Comment: http://www.burra.yabbit.net/node/74  trying to make thumbnails align H and now am trying that by this code field-label-inline .field-label,
.field-label-inline .field-items {
 text-align:center;
}
in my modify theme.css

Comment: @user12564 answer updated with example CSS for your case

Comment: thx but no doesn't work...only on initial view not content